# How do I change my default Qt Creator property window's Color picker?

Tags: qt, ide, preferences

I'm just familiarizing myself with QT Creator, and so I may use incorrect terminology.  I've been trying to research this myself, but must not be choosing my keywords properly.

I'm trying to find the location of the setting or preference within the Creator 8.0.1 IDE that allows me to see different properties of a selected object's colors instead of the one's presented by default.

Instead of this:

[image: My current default setup]

---

I'm hoping for this:

[image: Desired shown settings]

Also, and likely related, when I click the "Color" in the current setup, the Color Select Dialog that appears looks like this:

[image: Current color selector]

Is it possible, and I think it may fix itself if the properties color options issue above is solved, to have the default selector be this one?

[image: Desired selector]

If I double-click on an object within the design window, I get that selector, but if I click on the color within the properties panel, then I get the previous one.

I'm happy to provide any other info you may need:

- Qt Creator 8.0.1

QML imports:

- import QtQuick 2.15
- import QtQuick.Window 2.15
- import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ColorEditor you're showing is the Qt Design Studio custom [ColorEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qtquick-properties.html#picking-colors) for the [PropertyEditor](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/qtquick-properties-view.html). This was a change made in [QtDS 2.2 release](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-design-studio-2.2-released).

The first image is showing the integrated minimal color editor in the PropertyEditor, the second one is showing the old (pre QtDS 2.2) ColorEditor that needed a complete section. The decision was made that it needed a slimmer version of the ColorEditor and the full ColorEditor on demand. The third image is showing the new full ColorEditor of QtDS.

You can get the operation system ColorDialog in the new version of the QtDS ColorEditor by right-clicking on the ColorPicker in the full ColorEditor and choosing "Open Color Dialog" from the context menu.

[image]